# How can I specify xhr request with node.js + cheerio?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

The page I'm scrapping is detecting whether the request is ajax or simple one. How can I specify that ?

```
app.get('/gsb', function(res, req){
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://www.somesite.com/somepage/"
} ...
```

Now, this `somepage` detects whether its xhr or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX is typically indicated via the [X-Requested-With](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Requested-With#Requested-With) header in the request.

```
request({
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
  url: ...})
```

Try that and see if it does the trick.